# How can I possibly iterate through data after n:th row in a text file?

Tags: c#, file

I have a textfile where I think I need to iterate to get all data.
This is how the textfile is constructed:
From row 1-9 there is information about the company that will recieve the Invoice. 
The 10'th row show the amount of items.
For example if the 10'th row is 2 then the following rows looks like this:

> 11 Milk "description of first item"
>   12 4 "quantity of item 1"
>   13 25 "price"
>   14 Condoms "description of second item"
>   15 10 "quantity of item 2"
>   16 2.5 "price"

What I want to do now is go through the file step by step and then when i am att line 10, in some way iterate through the amount of items, int this case 2, and then create an object of the data in above text file. This is a five step procedure.
Algorithm:

1. Read the text file step by step
2. Add every row in a list
3. increment integer count by 1
4. Validate if count is equal to 9(the line before the amount of items)
5. If count is 9 iterate through the data that the row shows, in this case 2.

I fail to establish number 5 in my algorithm. Here is the algorithm interpreted into code:

```
 fstream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
            sReader = new StreamReader(fstream);
            invoice = new Invoice();
            List<string> s = new List<string>();
            List<Items> itms = new List<Items>();
            while ((line = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                s.Add(line);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
            {
                count++;
                //Step 4
                if (count == 9)
                {
                  //Step 5. 
                }
```

And how do I show that there should be two objects, one with the rows 11-13 as parameters(s[11], s[12], s[13]) and the other object with 14-16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines( file );          
// check number of lines here, make sure there are at least nine and
// that the count is a multiple of three
for( int i = 9; i < lines.Length; i += 3 )
{
    string desc = lines[i + 0],
           qty = lines[i + 1],
           price = lines[i + 2];
    // do work here (step 5)
}
```

There's also fancier ways of doing this, but this should get you started.